# Set warning result (or partial failure) on TeamCity build

Tags: nuget, teamcity

In my TeamCity instance I have a build that builds, packages and publushes a NuGet package from source.

This particular package has version hardcoded in build parameters and isn't being incremented on each build.

On the final step of the build, actual publish, in case I am trying to publish a package with the version that is already published, I get an error (NuGet Publish type step returns 1).

This return code marks entire build as failed, since there is a general condition to fail a build where any steps return anything other then 0.

I would like to have a third state of the build - partially successful, to indicate that even though everything went fine, the publish didn't happen. Is this possible via some trick in configuration? Any type of result would be sufficient, as long as it is not marked red as failed and is not totally green that won't let me see that it didn't publish.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "warning" result for a build config in TeamCity.

My suggestion would be that you move the Package/Publish steps into a separate build config that is triggered by a finish build trigger (success only) on your Build config. That way the build config can succeed, and the Package config may fail independently - you will see the results of both which should give you what you want.

Alternatively you can query your Nuget server if the package with the version you are about to produce already exists and do nothing in this case (or handle it differently). That should be doable with a little Powershell.